Allow function to be called with arguments in any order
Consider the following code:
#include <concepts>

struct T1 {};

struct T2 {};

struct T3 {};

struct T4 {};

void bar(T1, T2, T3, T4) {
}

template<typename T>
concept IsT = std::same_as<T, T1> || std::same_as<T, T2> ||
              std::same_as<T, T3> || std::same_as<T, T4>;

void foo(IsT auto x1, IsT auto x2, IsT auto x3, IsT auto x4) {
    // How to order the types of x1, x2, x3, x4 and call bar(x?, x?, x?, x?)?
}

int main() {
    foo(T1{},T2{},T3{},T4{}); // ok
    foo(T4{},T3{},T2{},T1{}); // ok
    foo(T3{},T2{},T1{},T4{}); // ok
    // ...
}

My intent is simple:

The user can call foo in any argument order, but finally
bar will be called with the arguments in the correct order.

The trivial solution is using brute-force to divide the 24 cases, which is obviously tedious and error-prone.
Is there a non-brute force way to solve this problem? I'm using C++20.

To be honest, I hope not. This would be a very "surprising" API for most (seasoned) C++ developers.  Can you explain WHAT you are trying to do and WHY you think this is a good idea?

What happens when bar takes multiple arguments of same type? Or types which can be converted?

@PepijnKramer, consider they are different option types. The user can use 1, 2, 3, or 4 options in any order. If missing, foo can use the default value to call bar.

@TanveerBadar, bar's argument types are distinct.

Perhaps tedious and error prone, but you can easily write a compile-time brute force solution for optimal run-time performance. I'd say take the win and move on!

There really isn't a way, you will be plagued with possible implicit type conversions. Note that even for designated initializers C++ chose to honor the order in which the members in the struct must be initialized. What you are trying to do is IMO against the spirit of C++'s type system

Related/duplicate of how-to-generate-all-the-permutations-of-function-overloads

@PepijnKramer: good example IMO is with date, where most permutation of year/month/day correspond to a locale.

@Jarod42 Good point.

You could have a single parameter struct, which you use as-if it were named parameters passed to the function.  (But I like Jarod42's clever answer better.  With the caveat of "please don't do this in real code.")

As types are different, you might wrap them in tuple, and get correct types afterward:
void foo(IsT auto x1, IsT auto x2, IsT auto x3, IsT auto x4) {
    auto t = std::tie(x1, x2, x3, x4);
    bar(std::get<T1&>(t), std::get<T2&>(t), std::get<T3&>(t), std::get<T4&>(t));
}

Demo
